# CURL_SETOPT_ARRAY Not working inside a function, but works alone

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create a query string from POST data that I already have set as the variables $email and $ip. It needs to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

could I use http_build_query? A little rusty here. I just need help pulling the variables and adding them to the string to POST.

Here is the section I'm working on. (Just using this for testing to see responses)

```
    function coSponsorPush2($email) {

        global $ip;
        global $email;

        $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '#',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(['email' => $email, 'ip_address' => $ip]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  ),
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: From the documentation: "This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data."

Comment: I might be overthinking this. I know I need it to be para1=val1&para2=val2, 

But how do I replace the values with my variables without switching to multipart/form-data?

Comment: As you suggest, `http_build_query` is the appropriate function to use to build the string

Comment: So like `$post = http_build_query([“email” => $email, “ip” => $ip]);`

Comment: Thanks Mike, I got it to work with this. However, when placed inside a function, it doesn't work. Edited the above code with the function.

Comment: You’ll want to look at how to pass parameters to functions, and when is an appropriate time to use thé `global` declaration. (Hint: it’s never)